# I've just upgraded to Monterey on my MacBook Air 2020 and now I can't play music through my bluetooth Samsung soundbar anymore

Tags: macos, ios, audio, bluetooth, monterey

I was able to just fine before the upgrade. I reset the connections on both devices, restarted a few times, restarted bluetooth, but no dice. Anybody else has this problem as well?

I did read that this was a problem with the early betas, but got patched out- and it seems to be back right now.

Possibly related, but my iOS 15 device also stopped connecting to my Samsung hardware directly after the update. I did reinstall the firmware on my soundbar, but no luck. I also tried connecting to it via some other devices that I own that support bluetooth audio and they work without a hitch, so it does seem to be related to MacOS and iOS.

Comment: The sound bar stopped connecting to your iPhone after you updated the iPhone to iOS 15, or after you updated your Mac to Monterey? Clarify, if you will.

Comment: Both! I couldn't connect my iPhone anymore after updating it to iOS 15, and I couldn't connect my Mac anymore after updating to Monterey.

Comment: Perhaps it is coincidental and the sound bar is malfunctioning? Do other Bluetooth devices connect to the speaker without a problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried connecting to it via some other devices that I own that support bluetooth audio and they work without a hitch

Comment: On the flip side, can you connect your Mac and iPhone to other Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Yes, that works fine! I tried it with a crappy Chinese bluetooth amp and a tiny JBL bluetooth speaker. Both connected immediately.

Comment: The Samsung is the weak link in the chain, then. TBH, perhaps an upgrade to a newer external sound device is in order. In the US, Black Friday can present some good deals on upgrades. I have two Anker SoundCore speakers and they really kick out for a relatively inexpensive outlay. I've used them near-field for better laptop Zoom calls, (the SoundCores have embedded mics, too, for telephony,) as well as in larger rooms and outdoors in the garden and at the fire-pit. _Note: No financial or other connection to Fantasia Trading LLC._

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I fixed it by first forgetting the soundbar on my macbook then repairing to it. I had to click the pair button on the sound bar remote for that. I'm not sure if we have the same sound bar though, mine is QT70.